# How do I develop an android app that reads aloud the text without using any button event?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Iam developing an app for visually challenged. As soon as the app opens, it has to read out the instructions on screen.

Comment: You write some code in Android Studio and then debug it :)

Comment: there are text2speech libraries out there to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You could kick off the voice reading in your Activity/Fragment's onResume().

Answer (score 0):

you can use text to speech (tts)
first of all declare an array of the int addresses of the strings used as instructions at the start of the activity 
for eg `int[] instructions={R.string.instruction1,R.string.instruction2,...}`

and now just play each string using tts using a for loop in the onCreate method